# How to run a D3 example

Tags: d3.js, observablehq

For example https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-treemap

If you paste the fragments of script into a `<script>` tag in a HTML file the (obviously) it doesn't work.

How are you supposed to run these things?

And what the heck is italic `f`?

Why are no statements terminated with a semicolon and why are things declared without `var`?

Surely this cannot possibly work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>H1</h1?

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
chart = {
  const x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
  const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]);

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

  let group = svg.append("g")
      .call(render, treemap(data));

  function render(group, root) {
    const node = group
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(root.children.concat(root))
      .join("g");

    node.filter(d => d === root ? d.parent : d.children)
        .attr("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("click", d => d === root ? zoomout(root) : zoomin(d));

    node.append("title")
        .text(d => `${name(d)}\n${format(d.value)}`);

    node.append("rect")
        .attr("id", d => (d.leafUid = DOM.uid("leaf")).id)
        .attr("fill", d => d === root ? "#fff" : d.children ? "#ccc" : "#ddd")
        .attr("stroke", "#fff");

    node.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", d => (d.clipUid = DOM.uid("clip")).id)
      .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", d => d.leafUid.href);

    node.append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", d => d.clipUid)
        .attr("font-weight", d => d === root ? "bold" : null)
      .selectAll("tspan")
      .data(d => (d === root ? name(d) : d.data.name).split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g).concat(format(d.value)))
      .join("tspan")
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("y", (d, i, nodes) => `${(i === nodes.length - 1) * 0.3 + 1.1 + i * 0.9}em`)
        .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, nodes) => i === nodes.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null)
        .attr("font-weight", (d, i, nodes) => i === nodes.length - 1 ? "normal" : null)
        .text(d => d);

    group.call(position, root);
  }

  function position(group, root) {
    group.selectAll("g")
        .attr("transform", d => d === root ? `translate(0,-30)` : `translate(${x(d.x0)},${y(d.y0)})`)
      .select("rect")
        .attr("width", d => d === root ? width : x(d.x1) - x(d.x0))
        .attr("height", d => d === root ? 30 : y(d.y1) - y(d.y0));
  }

  // When zooming in, draw the new nodes on top, and fade them in.
  function zoomin(d) {
    const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
    const group1 = group = svg.append("g").call(render, d);

    x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
    y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);

    svg.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(t => group0.transition(t).remove()
          .call(position, d.parent))
        .call(t => group1.transition(t)
          .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(0, 1))
          .call(position, d));
  }

  // When zooming out, draw the old nodes on top, and fade them out.
  function zoomout(d) {
    const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
    const group1 = group = svg.insert("g", "*").call(render, d.parent);

    x.domain([d.parent.x0, d.parent.x1]);
    y.domain([d.parent.y0, d.parent.y1]);

    svg.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(t => group0.transition(t).remove()
          .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(1, 0))
          .call(position, d))
        .call(t => group1.transition(t)
          .call(position, d.parent));
  }

  return svg.node();
}

data = FileAttachment("flare-2.json").json()

treemap = data => d3.treemap()
    .tile(tile)
  (d3.hierarchy(data)
    .sum(d => d.value)
    .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value))

function tile(node, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
  d3.treemapBinary(node, 0, 0, width, height);
  for (const child of node.children) {
    child.x0 = x0 + child.x0 / width * (x1 - x0);
    child.x1 = x0 + child.x1 / width * (x1 - x0);
    child.y0 = y0 + child.y0 / height * (y1 - y0);
    child.y1 = y0 + child.y1 / height * (y1 - y0);
  }
}

name = d => d.ancestors().reverse().map(d => d.data.name).join("/")
width = 954
height = 924
format = d3.format(",d")
d3 = require("d3@5")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Observable as a prototype tool you first have to know that they have a different flavor of Javascript. You can't just copy and paste the cells to a pure html/js file, but it's indeed very easy to use their ecosystem

Here are some links from their documentation

- [Observable’s not JavaScript](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript)

If you're prototyping and wants to quick embed your code

- [Downloading and Embedding Notebooks](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks)
- [Handy Embed Code Generator](https://observablehq.com/@jashkenas/handy-embed-code-generator)

Another resource on how to convert notebooks to standalone

- [Observable to Standalone](https://github.com/severo/observable-to-standalone)

Here is another similar questions with answer

[D3 example from Observable on my wordpress site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872678/d3-example-from-observable-on-my-wordpress-site/61878486#61878486)

Hopefully that works for you

Comment: Thank you, that makes it a bit clearer what's going on.

Comment: Gut feeling is that I don't want to add all that complexity to my MCV Core app.

Comment: It looks like the only way to make a d3 'notebook' is on their website? You can't just use a text editor?

Comment: there is a experimental unofficial vscode addon https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GordonSmith.observable-js  I haven't tested yet. there is a talk discussion on it here https://talk.observablehq.com/t/vscode-observable-js-extension-v0-4-2/3177

Comment: the runtime (opensource) is very lightweight and it's practical to use their online editor. downloading and embedding it's very straightforward

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can port your code from ObservableHQ to vanilla.js. You should be able to run this example with little to no modification.

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';
 var data = {};
 const  width = 954;
 const height = 924;
 const format = d3.format(",d");
 

 d3.json("/api/graph/flare.json").then(function (dt) {
    data = dt;        
    chart();

})
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
});

function chart(){
  treemap = dt => d3.treemap()
  .tile(tile)
  (d3.hierarchy(dt)
  .sum(d => d.value)
  .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value))
  
  const name = d => d.ancestors().reverse().map(d => d.data.name).join("/")

  const x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
  const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]);

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
  .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

  let group = svg.append("g")
  .call(render, treemap(data));
}

 function render(group, root) {
   const node = group
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(root.children.concat(root))
   .join("g");

   node.filter(d => d === root ? d.parent : d.children)
    .attr("cursor", "pointer")
    .on("click", d => d === root ? zoomout(root) : zoomin(d));

  node.append("title")
    .text(d => `${name(d)}\n${format(d.value)}`);

  node.append("rect")
    .attr("id", d => (d.leafUid = d3.select("leaf")).id)
    .attr("fill", d => d === root ? "#fff" : d.children ? "#ccc" : "#ddd")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff");

  node.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", d => (d.clipUid = d3.select("clip")).id)
    .append("use")
    .attr("xlink:href", d => d.leafUid.href);

  node.append("text")
    .attr("clip-path", d => d.clipUid)
    .attr("font-weight", d => d === root ? "bold" : null)
    .selectAll("tspan")
    .data(d => (d === root ? name(d) : d.data.name).split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g).concat(format(d.value)))
  .join("tspan")
    .attr("x", 3)
    .attr("y", (d, i, nodes) => `${(i === nodes.length - 1) * 0.3 + 1.1 + i * 0.9}em`)
    .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, nodes) => i === nodes.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null)
    .attr("font-weight", (d, i, nodes) => i === nodes.length - 1 ? "normal" : null)
    .text(d => d);

 group.call(position, root);
}

function position(group, root) {
    group.selectAll("g")
    .attr("transform", d => d === root ? `translate(0,-30)` :    `translate(${x(d.x0)},${y(d.y0)})`)
    .select("rect")
    .attr("width", d => d === root ? width : x(d.x1) - x(d.x0))
    .attr("height", d => d === root ? 30 : y(d.y1) - y(d.y0));
 }


function zoomin(d) {
  const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
  const group1 = group = svg.append("g").call(render, d);

  x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
  y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);

  svg.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(t => group0.transition(t).remove()
      .call(position, d.parent))
    .call(t => group1.transition(t)
      .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(0, 1))
      .call(position, d));
 }

function zoomout(d) {
  const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
  const group1 = group = svg.insert("g", "*").call(render, d.parent);

  x.domain([d.parent.x0, d.parent.x1]);
  y.domain([d.parent.y0, d.parent.y1]);

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(t => group0.transition(t).remove()
      .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(1, 0))
      .call(position, d))
      .call(t => group1.transition(t)
      .call(position, d.parent));
 }

  return svg.node();
}  



function tile(node, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
   d3.treemapBinary(node, 0, 0, width, height);
    for (const child of node.children) {
    child.x0 = x0 + child.x0 / width * (x1 - x0);
    child.x1 = x0 + child.x1 / width * (x1 - x0);
    child.y0 = y0 + child.y0 / height * (y1 - y0);
    child.y1 = y0 + child.y1 / height * (y1 - y0);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Has anyone actually managed to get the "zooming" working with VanillaJS version of this?  I've attempted using this, but it has the same issue I had with my VanillaJS port, which is that the `on("click",..)` handler never gets invoked, although the pointer is correctly changing for nodes with children.  Tried in Chrome and FF (Note also that in sample code the `tile` function scope needs to be at same level as zoomin/zoomout, etc.)